# Upload Base64 string to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In my App Engine method I sent a `base64 string` from my Android app and I want to upload that image to `Google Cloud Storage`.

I decode the string to a `byte[]` with

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
```

Then I create a `Storage` object to connect to it

```
Storage.Builder storageBuilder = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport,new JacksonFactory(),credential);
Storage storage = storageBuilder.build();
```

I have the bucket name and the image name but how do I insert the byte[] into storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply turn your byte[] into an InputStream. Java provides ByteArrayInputStream for just this purpose.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

public class ByteUploader {

  /* Simple function to upload a byte array. */
  public static void uploadByteStream(
      String bucket, String objectName, byte[] bytes, String contentType) throws Exception {
    InputStreamContent contentStream =
        new InputStreamContent(contentType, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject().setName(objectName);
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest =
        getService().objects().insert(bucket, objectMetadata, contentStream);
    insertRequest.execute();
  }

  /* Simple no-auth service */
  private static Storage getService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    return new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)
        .setApplicationName("myApplication")
        .build();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ByteUploader.uploadByteStream("yarbrough-test", "foobar",new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4}, "text/plain");
  }
}
```

Comment: the `Insert` object does not have `setContent()` only `setContentType()`. Those examples also may be out of date because the `storage.objects().insert` no longer accepts Inputstream and only accepts `AbstractInputStreamContent`

Comment: Hey, just got back to my desk. Here's a new version that actually, you know, works.

Comment: one other quick question, do you ahve to set the content type on the `StorageObject` if you are setting it on the inputstream?

Comment: I expect it'd probably work if you left it out of the metadata.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough pls add the code for same problem in python.